# How to return an HTML file in Django that is NOT a template?

Tags: django, templates

I have a particular HTML file that I want to show in Django. This file is generated externally and will *not* use Django template syntax. In fact, it includes some syntax that confuses the Django template generator (like `{{ #something }}`) and makes it return an error.

What is the best way to return this particular HTML page in a way that does not trigger the template syntax to be used? I use this now, and it works, but is this the recommended way? Any drawbacks?

```
def annual_report(request):
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    html_content = open("templates/reports/annualreport.html")
    return HttpResponse(html_content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to use `HttpResponse`, in fact `render` uses `HttpResponse` as base class, as well as `TemplateResponse` that's based on `SimpleTemplateResponse` with parent class [HttpResponse](https://github.com/django/django/blob/600ff26a85752071da36e3a94c66dd8a77ee314a/django/template/response.py#L138)